# Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and I wanted swagger-ui.html as home/welcome page and handel ROOT context (/)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, embedded-tomcat-8

I have spring boot 2 and swagger API page working at http://localhost:8448/portalapi/swagger-ui.html. But I wanted to map http://localhost:8448/ and http://localhost:8448/portalapi/ to forward the request to http://localhost:8448/portalapi/swagger-ui.html.  But it is not working.  It gives HTTP Status 404 – Not Found (tomcat default response). Any help or pointer is greatly appreciated.

appliacation.properties

```
##
# tomcat server port
server.port=8448
#server.address=0.0.0.0

server.servlet.contextPath=/portalapi/
```

This is a webconfig class to context to forward:

```
   @Configurable
    @Component
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            // forward requests to /admin and /user to their index.html
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName(
                    "forward:/portalapi/swagger-ui.html");
            registry.addViewController("/portalapi/").setViewName(
                    "forward:/portalapi/swagger-ui.html");
        }

    }
```

Comment: The dispatcher servlet is mapped to `/portalapi` hence `/` will not pass through the dispatcherservlet.

Comment: @M.Deinum,  how do I map /portalapi and  / to dispathServlet? can you please help ?

Comment: With `/` everything, including `/portalapi` are already mapped.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251849/set-up-a-server-the-servlet-contextpath-my-interceptor-is-based-on-the-my/57251920#57251920

Answer (score 1):

Change the below piece from :

```
@Configurable
@Component
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

to:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

Comment: It did not work.  As "/" is not mapped to dispatcherServlet.

Comment: In your application.properties, `server.servlet.contextPath=/portalapi/` means you will not be having any mapping to `/`, instead you should be using `/portalapi` which is your context root.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirect controller

```
@Controller
public class RedirectController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/portalapi/"})
    public String redirectToSwagger() {
        return "redirect:/portalapi/swagger-ui.html";
    }

}
```

Comment: It did not work.  As "/" is not mapped to dispatcherServlet.

Comment: Property file should not have server.servlet.contextPath=/portalapi/ or remove "/" from @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/portalapi/"})